# Whenever specific button clicked it does something in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

**Hello**.
Can anyone help me with scanning buttons always and when I click specific one it does something even Im writing? I want to be filling a record with like 9 attributes but when Im atc. at fourth I want to close it. I tried some readkey stuff :

```
procedure searching();
var p:char;search:string='';
begin
     repeat
       p:=readkey();
       write(p);
       search+=chr(p);
       until (p=#27) or (p=#13);
       if (p=#27) then menu()
       else
       ...
```

but the problem was that it written some character it was not possible to erase it and I knew that backspacing and writing again made my search filled with characters I did not wanted in there. Couldn't find a topic about it in pascal so im trying here. Don't flame for english please. Hope you get what I meant, also English is maybe the problem I can't find it, whatever. Waiting for answer, Thanks, Maroš.

Comment: Those are not *buttons*. They're *keys*. (Not being nitpicky - there is a major difference between keys on a keyboard and buttons on your screen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the problem was that it written some character it was not possible to erase it

Why not? Just handle #8 (backspace) and truncate your last character from the `search` string. You can use both `System.Delete` (by deleting the last character) and `System.SetLength` (by setting the length to current length - 1).

Comment: Thank you I will try that. I was just wondering if there is any "nicer" solution to that. Thanks for helping, im gonna try if it will work out.

Comment: SOLVED Thank you !